# Adding External filters for Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

What i want to achieve is:

- Have a Master Grid. Clicking on a row of this grid, i want to filter the rows of the ChildGrid.

What i have done so far:

```
function updateChildGridRows(field, operator, value) {    
// get the kendoGrid element.
var gridData = $("#childGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var filterField = field;
var filterValue = value;
// get currently applied filters from the Grid.
var currFilterObj = gridData.dataSource.filter();

// if the oject we obtained above is null/undefined, set this to an empty array
var currentFilters = currFilterObj ? currFilterObj.filters : [];

// iterate over current filters array. if a filter for "filterField" is already
// defined, remove it from the array
// once an entry is removed, we stop looking at the rest of the array.
if (currentFilters && currentFilters.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < currentFilters.length; i++) {
        if (currentFilters[i].field == filterField) {
            currentFilters.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (filterValue != "") {
    currentFilters.push({
        field: filterField,
        operator: "eq",
        value: filterValue
    });
}

gridData.dataSource.filter({
    filters: currentFilters
}); }
```

I got this code from the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/randombw/27hTK/

I have attached the MasterGrid's Change event to MasterGridSelectionChange() method. From there i am calling my filter method.

But when i click on the MasterGrid's row, all of the rows in my ChildGrid are getting removed.

One thing i can understand is, if i give wrong column name in the filter list, all the rows will be removed. But even though i have given correct ColumnName, my rows are getting deleted.

Sorry for the long post.

Please help me with this issue, as i am stuck with this for almost 4 days!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define ClientDetailTemplateId for the master grid and ToClientTemplate() for the Child grid

read [Grid Hierarchy](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy) for a example

Comment: thanks. Even though this is not the answer i was looking for, Grid Hierarchy really gives a better way of implementing what i want.